# Access file outside project directory after publishing dashboard to RSConnect

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, rsconnect

I have a Shiny dashboard and it is published to **RSConnect**. But some of my files are outside the project directory and the paths are referring to that files, also I am loading packages from a folder outside the project directory.So the dashboard is not loading in RSConnect.
Is there any way to publish the dashboard to RSConnect with files outside the project directory?
It would we great if someone could help on the same.

Comment: You'll need to put the files in the same directory as the app.R (or ui.R/server.R) file (or sub-directories from here).

Comment: There are  lot of files which cant be moved to any other location due to some issues. So we cant move the files to the same directory or to the sub directories

Comment: I'm happy to be corrected, but this is your only option.